# Inserting javascript in web page

Tags: c#, vb.net, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

Hy, First i have a question, how to insert javascript into webpage that already have a script tag 
For example:
in the web page, there is javascript code

```
function win(){
alert("your score is 500"); }
```

i want to insert alert("Winner!"); above alert("your score is 500");
so the code will look like in the web page:

```
function win(){
alert("Winner!");
alert("your score is 500"); }
```

i have tried with this code

```
WebBrowser1.Document.Body.AppendChild(WebBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script")) 
WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("win", New [Object]() {"(function() { alert('Winner!'); alert('your score is 500');})()"})
```

but it is not working,
coul you help me? thank you

Comment: What happened when you ran the above code? Were there any exceptions?

Comment: there is no effect

Comment: i am sorry, edited use '

Comment: how to modify the function usin webbrowser control

Answer (score 0):

Why create new script tag and append to head element when it already exists ?

You may try :

```
HtmlElementCollection elems = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("script");
IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)elems[0];
element.text = "function win() { alert('Winner!');alert('your score is 500');}";
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("win");
```

Caution : haven't actually tested the code, hope this helps !

Comment: do you get a script tag allright ? i.e. elems is not empty 
if yes, then make sure you receive a script tag at elem[0] ?

Comment: IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)elems[0];
this line contain error
" can not convert type system.windows.form.htmlelement to mshtml.ihtmlscripelement "